# How to conditionally implement a template function using a template parameter in a template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I understand that the question sounds a little confusing but bear with me. As I hope that this example might at the bare minimum give you an idea of what I am asking.

**If you have a better name for this question, please don't refrain from informing me about it and I shall change it straight away**

So here we go!

Suppose I have a class

```cpp
template <size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes> class malloc_ptr
```

inside of which I have a method

```cpp
template <typename cast_type, bool should_use_c_cast> cast_type cast();
```

---

Here is the entire class;

```cpp
template <size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes>
class malloc_ptr
{
private:
    void* ptr;

public:
    malloc_ptr()
        : ptr(malloc(size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes)) {}

    template <typename cast_type , bool should_use_c_cast>
    cast_type cast();

    ~malloc_ptr() noexcept
        { free(ptr); }
};
```

---

I understand that I can implement the function like this [with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283261/template-function-in-a-templated-class]

```cpp
template<size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes> 
template<class cast_type, bool should_use_c_cast> 
cast_type malloc_ptr<size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes>::cast()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<cast_type>(ptr);
}
```

However I only want the function to be implemented when `should_use_c_cast == true` but I have no clue on how to do that.

---

I hope that you all could help with this. Moreover, any help would be greatly appreciated.
And Thank You in advance!

Comment: Look up `enable_if`

Comment: Or use `requires` with c++20.

Comment: Are you intending on handling the `!should_use_c_cast` case as well?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that's why I am trying to find how `enable_if ` actually works

Comment: See [how `enable_if` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284499/how-does-stdenable-if-work)

Comment: Ah, well unfortunately you can't partially specialise function templates.

Comment: @Caleth I guess its not such a big problem as I can always just rely on good ol' `if` statements to `return` only what I want the function to return.

Comment: What is the purpose of that `bool` which should be always true (and provided by user)?

Comment: @Jarod42 It will only be called by me. It will not be a `bool` but a `constexpr` expression (such as checking *equality*, *arithmetic*, ...) which would simplify to a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `enable_if` as shown below:

```
template <size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes>
class malloc_ptr
{
private:

public:
    
    template <typename cast_type , bool should_use_c_cast>
//-------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------->condition here
    std::enable_if_t<should_use_c_cast,cast_type> cast();

};
```

---

With C++20 you can use `requires`:

```
template <size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes>
class malloc_ptr
{
private:

public:
    
    template <typename cast_type , bool should_use_c_cast>
    cast_type cast() requires(should_use_c_cast);

};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have one implementation for true, and one for false, you need C++17's `if constexpr`, because you can't partially specialise a function template.

```
template<size_t size> 
template<class cast_type, bool should_use_c_cast> 
cast_type malloc_ptr<size>::cast()
{
    if constexpr (should_use_c_cast) {
        return reinterpret_cast<cast_type>(ptr);
    } else {
        // false case here
    }
}
```

However, your `should_use_c_cast` case has undefined behaviour, so I'd suggest you don't even need `should_use_c_cast`, and instead use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). It is also suspicious that you are using `malloc`, because objects have alignment requirements, so if `malloc` returns an unaligned pointer, your program will again have undefined behaviour.

```
template <size_t size, size_t align = size>
class malloc_ptr
{
private:
    void* ptr;

public:
    malloc_ptr()
        : ptr(aligned_alloc(align, size)) {}

    template <typename cast_type>
    cast_type * cast();

    ~malloc_ptr() noexcept
        { free(ptr); }
};

template<size_t size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes> 
template<class cast_type> 
cast_type * malloc_ptr<size_of_allocated_memory_in_bytes>::cast()
{
    return new (ptr) cast_type;
}
```

Comment: But aren't `if` statements `constexpr` by default?

Comment: @AmritSanjeev no. When `should_use_c_cast` is true, the else branch does not need to be valid C++, and vice-versa

Comment: Pretty much like macros then?

Comment: No, it's entirely unlike a macro. It is like `#if #else #endif`

Comment: Oh like pre-processor symbols, but better?

Comment: In that it interacts with template parameters, yes

Comment: I think I can use this conjunction with `std::enable_if` to disable any function I don't want. Again thank you!